# Swift expose the protocol to objc in protocol oriented programming

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, interop

I have this code which works well:

```
public protocol PermissionProvider {
  static func authorizationStatus(for mediaType: AVMediaType) -> AVAuthorizationStatus
}
extension AVCaptureDevice: PermissionProvider {}
```

Now I need to expose the protocol to Objc runtime:

```
@objc // added this attribute
public protocol PermissionProvider {
  static func authorizationStatus(for mediaType: AVMediaType) -> AVAuthorizationStatus
}
extension AVCaptureDevice: PermissionProvider {}
```

But I got an error saying:

```
AVFoundation.AVCaptureDevice:4:21: error: Objective-C method 'authorizationStatusForMediaType:' provided by method 'authorizationStatus(for:)' does not match the requirement's selector ('authorizationStatusFor:')
    open class func authorizationStatus(for mediaType: AVMediaType) -> AVAuthorizationStatus
```

From the error message, it looks like related to some naming convention between objc and swift. I wonder how i can fix the compile error?

The reason I introduced this protocol is that, I need to unit test and inject this "permission provider". And the reason I need to expose it to objc is that, some of the caller is still in ObjC

Edit:

I created an empty project, then created a new file with the above code, and got the error

[image]

Comment: When you add `@objc` to the protocol does it give you the error? @Paulw11

Comment: The 2nd chunk of code is everything I have that will reproduce the error.

Comment: Did you forget the `extension AVCaptureDevice: PermissionProvider {}`

Comment: Just created a new project, and got the error reproduced. (See screenshot)

Comment: What do you mean by swift definition? AVFoundation is in ObjC i believe.

Comment: I updated the question to explain why I need to expose this protocol

Comment: I believe AVCaptureDevice is a subclass of NSObject, which is implicitly `@objc` (same reason you don't have to mark your custom NSObject subclass `@objc` in order to expose it to objc runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the @objc attribute on the protocol method to specify a different method name to be exposed to Objective-C, in this case match it to the relevant method of `AVCaptureDevice` (`authorizationStatusForMediaType:`):

```
@objc // added this attribute
public protocol PermissionProvider {
    @objc(authorizationStatusForMediaType:) static func authorizationStatus(for mediaType: AVMediaType) -> AVAuthorizationStatus
}
extension AVCaptureDevice: PermissionProvider {}
```

### Why?

When Objective-C methods are mapped into Swift, argument descriptions that match the type of the corresponding parameter are pruned (see [SE-0005 'Better Translation of Objective-C APIs into Swift'](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md)), but when Swift is mapped into Objective-C a corresponding 'de-pruning' doesn't happen.

For example, if in Objective-C we have defined:

```
- (NappingStatus)nappingStatusForKoala:(Koala *)koala;

- (NappingStatus)nappingStatusForEchidna:(Koala *)koala;
```

when mapped into Swift these will become:

```
func nappingStatus(for: Koala) -> NappingStatus

func nappingStatus(forEchidna: Koala) -> NappingStatus
```

Notice in the first method `Koala` has been pruned from the parameter name because it matches the type of the parameter it is describing, but in the second method `Echidna` hasn't been pruned because this doesn't match the type of of the parameter it is describing (Koala).

When mapping from Swift to Objective-C, reversal of this pruning doesn't happen. For example, if in Swift we have defined

```
func nappingStatus(for: Koala) -> NappingStatus
```

when mapped into Objective-C it will become:

```
- (NappingStatus)nappingStatusFor:(Koala *)koala;
```

So for your case the AVCaptureDevice method in Objective-C that is:

```
+ (AVAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatusForMediaType:(AVMediaType)mediaType;
```

in Swift is mapped to (notice MediaType pruned):

```
class func authorizationStatus(for mediaType: AVMediaType) -> AVAuthorizationStatus
```

However your protocol method, which in Swift is:

```
static func authorizationStatus(for mediaType: AVMediaType) -> AVAuthorizationStatus
```

when mapped into Objective-C will be (notice MediaType not `de-pruned'):

```
+ (AVAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatusFor:(AVMediaType)mediaType;
```

which doesn't match the Objective-C method in AVCaptureDevice, so we just provide the correct Objective-C method name via the @objc attribute:

```
@objc(authorizationStatusForMediaType:) static func authorizationStatus(for mediaType: AVMediaType) -> AVAuthorizationStatus
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more? why should i rename it? is it because it was renamed in avfoundation code itself using NS_SWIFT_NAME?

Comment: Have added some more information to the answer to explain why this is needed.